# how to get grid's row data when in cell button is clicked

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
  <kendo-grid-column field="iban" title="IBAN">
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-command-column title="command">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="btnCommand($event)">Approve</button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

At the moment, the <kbd>Approve</kbd> button is just posting the event click event, how can it post the whole row data?

Here is the event handler

```js
btnCommand($event) {
  console.log($event)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in arguments to the `<ng-template>` tag using it's `let` signature. And send it back to the event handler as it's argument.

Try the following

```html
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-data>
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="btnCommand(data)">Approve</button>
</ng-template>
```

Event handler:

```js
public btnCommand(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

#### Update: Additional buttons

If you need to have additional buttons with different event handling behaviors, it's better to bind different event handlers.

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-data>
  <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onApprove(data)">Approve</button>
  <button class="btn" (click)="onDecline(data)">Decline</button>
</ng-template>
```

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
public onApprove(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
  // do something else
}

public onDecline(data: any) {
  console.log(data);
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,if i add one more button there call it Decline,is it possible to see which button is clicked?

Comment: @masali: What do you mean which button is clicked? Why not bind different event handlers if the behavior is different? I've posted an update.